Phase Identification and Relative Orientation in Heterojunctions
I have a heterojunction composed of TiO2 and CdSe and I would like to create a model in VESTA. Does using peak identification in XRD apply to heterojunctions as well? Additionally, is there a way to determine the relative orientation between the two constituents?
